# 'onclick' event function in document is never being fired

Tags: javascript

The problem I'm facing is that currently I have 2 elements, one is visible by default and the other one is hidden. When a button is clicked the state in both elements are exchanged, which means that the element which was not visible not it is and viceversa. What I want to accomplish now is that when I click in any other part of the page except in that given element, the state is reversed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hidesearch() {
        var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
        if (event.currentTarget == target) {
            document.getElementById('elem1').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('elem2').style.display = "true";
        }
    }

    function showsearch() {
        document.getElementById('elem2').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('elem1').style.display = "true";
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
</script>
```

This is the current code inside my `head` tag. Tried to add the `onclick` and `onload` attributes into the `body` too but isn't working still.

```
<h:body onload="hidesearch();"/>"
```

The page is .xhtml as everything is being coded using JSF + BootsFaces.

Is there anything I'm missing out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

document.getElementById('elem2').style.display = "true";

display property value of element style can be "block", "inline-block", "inline", "none" but "true" value doesn't exist.

Please assign appropriate value one you want.

Comment: To check available options for display value, please check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Comment: It still isn't working properly, the event is still not being fired.

Comment: which one isn't firing out? <body onload> or <body onclick>?

Comment: Is this right one <h:body onload="hidesearch();/>"?

Comment: I think it should be <h:body onload="hidesearch();"/>

Comment: Any of both actually. Yeah, I actually have it like that. `<h:body onload="hidesearch();"> <!-- Content here --> </body>` (or onclick, I'm trying with both)